# Is there anyway to check what chocolatey is passing Powershell from installArguments?

Tags: powershell, chocolatey

I'm trying to install an MSI that takes arguments with chocolatey

The msiexec command looks like

```
msiexec.exe /i path_to_msi UNAME="" PASS="" SQLSERVER="" CHKFRONTEND="1" CHKBACKEND="1" /quiet
```

My ps1 file has the following code in it

```
Start-Process -file 'bin\Release\Installer.msi' -args '/qn' -passthru | wait-process
```

and here is the cinst

```
cinst isbu -source %cd% -installArguments ‘UNAME=''user'' PASS=''pass'' SQLSERVER=''1.1.1.1'' CHKFRONTEND=''1'' CHKBACKEND=''0''’
```

When the CHKBACKEND is set to "1" it will interact with a sql database. But when it is set to 0 it skips it entirely.

I looked in Windows Event Viewer and it is saying it is failing on the sql database which it shouldn't even be interacting with. So I'm guessing the issue is somewhere when chocolatey sends the install args to powershell. Is there anywhere I can check what choco is passing? I looked in Event Viewer and didn't see anything in there.

Comment: IIRC, Chocolately stores all it's transient files in `$ENV:Temp`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see what chocolatey is doing here, just pass `-debug`

I noticed that you are calling the MSI yourself here and not using Chocolatey's built in methods, which would make use of -installArgs, I'd suggest reading through [CreatePackages](https://github.com/chocolatey/chocolatey/wiki/CreatePackages)

And then take a look at the [Helper Reference](https://github.com/chocolatey/chocolatey/wiki/HelpersReference), specifically [Install-ChocolateyInstallPackage](https://github.com/chocolatey/chocolatey/wiki/HelpersInstallChocolateyInstallPackage)

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. It looks like chocolatey is passing the installArguments correctly. Is there something I need to do in the nuspec to get it to pass those onto the powershell that calls the msi?